# Probability notation for a function of a random variable

Tags: probability, notation

Suppose I'm interested in $\Pr(g(x)=1)$, where $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\{0,1\}$.

In this context, $x$ is the realization of a random variable, $X$. I would like to emphasize this by rewriting the probability as: 
$$
\Pr(g(x)=1) = \Pr(g(X)=1 \mid X=x)
$$ 
Is it kosher to write this? Or am I violating some rule of conditional probability?

Answer (score 3):

Generally you would just write

$$ P(g(X) = 1) $$

for this, with the understanding that $X$ is a random varaible.

Answer (score 3):

Your displayed equation do not make sense! it says (copied here)
$$
         \Pr(g(x)=1) = \Pr(g(X)=1 \mid X=x)
$$ 
with $X$ the random variable, and $x$ some specific possible value of $X$. Then we will have
$$
\Pr(g(x)=1) = \begin{cases}  
                     1, & \text{if $g(x)=1$} \\  
                     0, & \text{if $g(x)\not= 1$}
              \end{cases}   
$$
simply since there is no randomness in $g(x)$! The right hand part is $\Pr(g(X)=1 \mid X=x)$, but given $X0x$ we have that $g(X)$ reduces to $g(x)$, so again the randomness disappears. So while the equation is correct, it is uninteresting, reducing to either $0=0$ or to $1=1$.